# Pattern matching a struct with a String

Tags: string, pattern-matching, rust

Is it possible to pattern match a String field? I can't make this code work.

```
struct Foo {
    x: int,
    y: int,
    str: String
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = Foo { x: 1, y: 2 , str: "Hi".to_string()};
    match a {
        Foo { x: x, y: y, str: "Hi".to_string() } => println!("Found {}, {}", x, y),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

```
<anon>:10:36: 10:37 error: expected one of `,` or `...`, found `.`
<anon>:10         Foo { x: x, y: y, str: "Hi".to_string() } => println!("Found {}, {}", x, y),
                                             ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`match` cases may not contain expressions like `"Hi".to_string()`, only constants (e.g. `3`, `"Hi`") or variables (e.g. `x`). To match on a `String` field you will need to use pattern guards:

```
match a {
    Foo { x: x, y: y, str: ref str } if str == &"Hi" =>
        println!("Found {}, {}", x, y),
    _ => {}
}
```

The `if str == &"Hi"` is the pattern guard to check the value of the `String`. Note that the pattern guard forces us to use `ref` to capture a reference to the `String`, rather than moving it out of the struct.